# Select em entity framework com determinadas colunas

Tags: entity-framework-6

Estou tentando fazer um ***select*** em uma tabela que contém várias colunas e quero que o comando ***sql*** que o **EntityFramework** gera contenha apenas as colunas que especifiquei.

Meu código está assim:

```cs
var clientes = (from cliente in repositoryCliente.GetAll()
    select new
    {
        cliente.Id,
        cliente.Nome,
        cliente.Email,
        cliente.Telefone
    }).ToList();
```

E meu repository:

```cs
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
{
    return _dbSet;
}
```

Mas ao analisar o comando sql que ele faz, ele busca todos os outros campos
(Estou usando Entity Framework Profiler)

Eu quero que ele execute apenas o comando sql `"Select Id,Nome,Email,Telefone from Cliente"`, e não com as demais colunas.

Comment: Não vejo isso como tendo algum ganho, mas mesmo assim vou responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é ao usar IEnumerable

O mesmo faz com que busque todos os campos e registros, ignorando os métodos do LINQ ou Lambda do Entity Framework.

Para contornar isso, deve-se utilizar

IQueryable

O mesmo contribui também para performance em consultas com o Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2):

O Entity Framework trabalha com select tendo como padrão de comportamento selecionar todas as colunas. Se mesmo assim é desejável especificar a nível de SQL quais colunas deverão ser usadas, o método `SqlQuery` de `DbSet` cumpre essa função:

```cs
using (var entidades = new dbContext())
{                
    var clientes = entidades.Clientes.SqlQuery("select Id, Nome, Email, Telefone 
        from Clientes").ToList();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Vê se ajuda: **[entity-framework-select-multiple-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536064/entity-framework-select-multiple-columns)**

```cs
var dataset2 =
    (from recordset in entities.processlists
     where recordset.ProcessName == processname
     select new
     {
         serverName = recordset.ServerName,
         processId = recordset.ProcessID,
         username = recordset.Username
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: É exatamente o mesmo código que eu coloquei ali na pergunta...

Comment: Você tem que atribuir, armazenar, os itens do select em um objeto: serverName = recordset.ServerName. Você não está fazendo isso

Comment: Mesma coisa, buscou todos as colunas...